# How to write tests for generic method used to insert queries

Tags: python, testing

I have a database class and this class contains a method used to insert records. This is how the method looks:

```
def insertRecord(self, **kwargs):
    if 'table' not in kwargs.keys():
        raise Exception('The table keyword is required')

    table = kwargs['table']
    del kwargs['table']

    query_fields = kwargs.keys()
    pg_fields = []

    for field in query_fields:
        pg_fields.append('%(' + field + ')s')

    query_field_string = ', '.join(query_fields)
    query_pg_string = ', '.join(pg_fields)

    self.cur.execute('INSERT INTO ' + table + '(' + 
        query_field_string + ') VALUES (' + query_pg_string + ')',
        kwargs
     )

    self.conn.commit()
```

The method accepts variable arguments list so the user can use this method to insert entries in any table. Bassically, the method is constructing a query string of the form `INSERT INTO <table>(<field1>, <field2>...) VALUES (%(field1)s, %(field2)s...)`, since the `execute` method accepts as the second argument a dictionary of the form `<field>: <value>` all the strings of the form %(field)s will be replaced with the corresponding value.

Basically, the method works fine, but I don't know how should I test it. Should I make a test database and see if the values passed to it are in the database after calling it? How would you write tests for such a method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor the code to format the SQL command, then test *that*.  In this way it's much simpler -- pass in args, get a formatted string and a dictionary back.  No mocking needed.

### source

```
# python -m unittest insertrec

import unittest

def formatInsert(table, **kwargs):
    assert table

    query_fields = kwargs.keys()
    pg_fields = []

    for field in query_fields:
        pg_fields.append('%(' + field + ')s')

    query_field_string = ', '.join(query_fields)
    query_pg_string = ', '.join(pg_fields)

    return (
        'INSERT INTO ' + table + '(' + 
        query_field_string + ') VALUES (' + query_pg_string + ')',
        kwargs
    )


class TestInsert(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_err_notable(self):
        self.assertRaises(AssertionError, formatInsert, None)

    def test_insert1(self):
        self.assertEquals(
            formatInsert('mytab', beer='tasty'),
            ('INSERT INTO mytab(beer) VALUES (%(beer)s)', 
             {'beer': 'tasty'}
             ),
        )
```